# Cocos2d font : How to create .fnt file for CCLabelBMFont? ( Any free bitmap font creation tool ? )

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Cocos2d: How to create .fnt file for font texture atlas?

Any free bitmap font creation tool?

Now I have all single character image.. and created texture grid in photoshop, is there any free software that make texture grid and .fnt file with trimmed font and coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's no tool that does exactly what you want. Since the .fnt file is simply an XML file you can create it manually.

The most widely used free bitmap font tool that works on Macs is Hiero. I wrote a [Hiero tutorial](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/knowledge-base/tutorial-bitmap-fonts-hiero/) that explains how to install, use and workaround some of its bugs.

[Glyph Designer](http://glyphdesigner.71squared.com/) is a far better tool however. It costs $29.99 and is well worth it.

But as far as I know neither tool supports the creation of a fnt file from an existing atlas texture.

Comment: thx for the info sir, but I have all single texture image also now I created new texture grid frm Zwoptex tool. But its coordinate is in .plist not .fnt. Now I will checkout Hiero tutorial.

Comment: I never got Hiero to work. It just crashes all the time. Zwoptex could be used... if someone wrote a .plist → .fnt converter tool. Did someone do it? (or do I need to do it?:-P)

Comment: Hiero is so buggy I don't recommend it anymore, not even considering its free nature.

Answer (score 2):

My solution has been to create the atlas using this tool: http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/. After this I have entered manually the .fnt description file. It works! :D

Comment: That is my question as well. Everybody seems to mention that you have to go manual, but what are the specifications for fnt-files? Which parameters are expected? A link on the subject maybe?

Comment: Parameters id, x, y, width, height, and page are easy. But how to use xoffset, yoffset, xadvance, and chnl? chnl is probably character new-line (0=no, 1=yes)? I can image what xoffset and yoffset would do, but from other examples cannot seem to logically explain the values.

Comment: @ViggoV I have found a document explaining the specifications for fnt: http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/doc/file_format.html

Comment: @LenArt `chnl` means "The texture channel where the character image is found (1 = blue, 2 = green, 4 = red, 8 = alpha, 15 = all channels)". You can see the meanings of all fnt parameters from [the link](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/doc/file_format.html).

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [bmGlyph](http://www.bmglyph.com/) for Mac. It costs 9.99$ in AppStore but it's working and it fulfills my needs so I think it's worth it. I don't know how it is in comparation with Glyph Designer, but it's at least a lot cheaper.

With bmGlyph you can import any font and then adjust colors, shadows, gradients, outline and a lot more. It has Cocos2D-support and it exports your fonts to .png and .fnt that you can load in cocos2D using CCLabelBMFont.