# .ttf kerning in iOS: how read kerning info?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, kerning

I use custom font in iOS application (cocos2d, OpenGL) and there is no kerning. Font already have kerning info (on my Mac in TextEdit and Pages kerning pairs looks fine), but when I use this font in application — kerning don't apply. Is there some way to use kerning pairs with custom .ttf font in iOS application?

Comment: Were you ever able to get kerning to work? I'm having the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641135/font-not-kerning-in-ios

Answer (score 0):

This is not answer for your question.

Alternative solution to get .fnt file for kern purpose.

[How to create .fnt file for cocos2d font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279384/cocos2d-how-to-create-fnt-file-for-font-texture-atlas)