# Font not kerning in iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, truetype, kerning, fontforge

I've created a custom font using FontForge for use in my iOS app. When I use the font in my app, kerning is not being applied. There is a known bug that kerning is not being applied for UITextView. I'm using this in a UILabel and UITextField, so that's not the issue. I'm targeting iOS 5.0.

I'm able to view the font in Font Book and Pages and see that kerning is working. However, kerning doesn't work in Word for Mac. I have enabled kerning in Word, but it does not work there. I'm not concerned so much about Word. I primarily want this to work in iOS.

I've created the font as both .otf and .ttf fonts, with a variety of the FontForge options for generating the font set.
Options I've played with are Apple, OpenType and OT/Old Style and OT/DSIG. Pages will properly apply kerning for all combinations of the font generation options, except when just OpenType is checked. Font Book will only show kerning when Apple is checked and nothing else.
I've read some comments on other forums about getting fonts to work with Word, but not anything specific about kerning and iOS.

Anyone have any experience:

**1) successfully creating a kerned font on OS X using FontForge for an iOS app?**

**OR**

**2) successfully creating a kerned font on OS X using FontForge that works in Word?** This might get me closer, even if you've not had experience with fonts on iOS.

I have a trial version of Glyphs that I've played with, but I don't want to have to move to another font program to get this done.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you enable the Kerning in Word, cause it's disabled by default.

Comment: Hi, Does your kerning work in MS word? or your problem is with the Mac?

Comment: I have enabled kerning in Word. Still does not work. Kerning does work in Pages on the Mac. The question though is about getting this to work in iOS. Will edit my question.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 6 (and below) UIKit controls like `UILabel`, `UITextView` and `UITextField` use WebKit under the hood to render their contents. WebKit doesn't honor a font's built-in kerning. iOS 6 introduced attributed text support for all UIKit controls. If you set the `attributedText` property of a `UILabel` instead of the regular `text` property then CoreText rendering will kick in and you'll get proper kerning. However, in iOS 6 there's a bug with `UITextField` where font kerning will still be wrong even if setting `attributedText`.

If you really need proper kerning for labels in iOS 5 there's a lot of great drop-in replacements. I use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) but [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) is also great.

If you really need proper kerning for a `UITextField` you're probably going to want to use Omni's `OUIEditableFrame`. The downside is that's a pain to integrate into a project. I recently went through the learning process a wrote a [lengthy tutorial](http://sandmoose.com/post/53903897669/how-to-use-ouieditableframe-with-the-omnigroup) if you're interested.

Comment: Michael, thanks for the reply. Since I'm stuck with iOS for my client's app, I'll take a look at your references. I'm going to upvote your answer until I am able to test it out. I may still have issues with the font file itself. Thanks!

Comment: Meant to say iOS 5. Wondering why I can't edit my comment. Might not get to testing your suggestions for a while. The app is in the App Store now (without kerning) and I'm on other projects until my client requests updates.